# Batch Script Function call working improperly

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scripting

I have written simple batch script to perform two separate functions based on the parameters. But whenever I am running the script in cmd with "service test" parameter its is calling ProcessKill function. Could you someone please help me understand what is happening here.

```
@Echo Off
set jobName=%1
set pidORServiceName=%2
echo %jobName%
echo %pidORServiceName%
cd "%~dp0"
>ServiceRestart.log 2>&1 (

if %jobName%==pkill (
    echo "Calling ProcessKill function"
    call:ProcessKill 
)
if %jobName%==service (
    echo "Calling RestartService function"
    call:RestartService 
)   
)

:ProcessKill
echo "killing the process" + %pidORServiceName%
taskkill /f /pid %pidORServiceName%
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ( 
   echo "Some error occurred with errorlevel" + %ERRORLEVEL%
) else (
   echo "killed the process"
)
goto:eof

:RestartService
echo "Restarting the service"
goto:eof
```

**cmd run output:**

```
ServicesRestart.bat service test
service
test
"killing the process" + test
ERROR: The process "test" not found.
"Some error occurred with errorlevel" + 128
```

**ServiceRestart.log**

```
"Calling RestartService function"
"Restarting the service"
```

The log file shows that ProcessKill function was not called but the output in cmd shows that it is getting called, not able understand which one is correctly telling the picture. Please adivse.

Comment: You need a `GOTO :EOF` before the `:ProcessKill` label.

Comment: It seems to solve the issue but could you please elaborate little more as I am pretty new to batch script.

Comment: You are assuming that the `CALL` works like a function in other modern programming languages.  It does not.  You need a `GOTO :EOF` before the `:ProcessKill` label for the same reason you need a `GOTO :EOF` before the `:RestartService` label.  Batch files will always process each line of the batch file from the top down unless you instruct it otherwise.

Comment: Just to make sure my understanding is correct, the difference between cmd output and log file was because the ProcessKill function is not getting called from inside of ( ) and hence its not captured in log file. But since in cmd it will call each line it is calling Processkill and prinitng the output in cmd.

Comment: every output between`>ServiceRestart.log` and the `)` just before the label `:ProcessKill` will be redirected to the file. The mystery lies in what happens *after* that code-block is executed. First item is that the redirection is no longer in effect so messages appear on the console. Second issue is that batch simply continues processing, so by "flow-through" the `:ProcessKill` routine is executed again. `test` has just been killed, so the `:ProcessKill` routine reports that it was not found - to the console since the redirection has been terminated, and the `goto :eof` terminates the batch.